# Height da div total proporcional ao conteudo

Tags: css3

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="slideShow">
  <div class="boxSlide">
     <div class="imagens">
       <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" />
       <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" />
       <img src="_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" />
     </div>
     <div class="anterior">
        <span class="setaSpan"><</span>
        <span class="boxSpan"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="proximo">
        <span class="setaSpan">></span>
        <span class="boxSpan"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contador">
     <span class="contaSlide">1</span>
     <span class="contaSlide">2</span>
     <span class="contaSlide">3</span>
  </div>
</div>
TESTE
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de fazer com que a altura da `div.slideShow`, seja automaticamente ajustada à altura das **div's** do seu interior.

A ideia aqui é de que o **navegador** seja ajustado (tamanhos de tela) e a proporção se mantenha.

Antes da `div.slideShow`, só existe o `body`.

O que eu quero fazer é que, à medida que a tela for sendo redimensionada, ou puxando as brodas do **navegador** ou mesmo através de telas predispostas (nb's, tablet's, celulares, etc...), a altura da `div.slideShow`, se ajuste à altura da do seu conteúdo interno que está já está sendo redimensionado corretamente.

Porém, se eu der altura fixa à `div.slideShow`, quando as imagens diminuírem de tamanho, vou ter problemas.

Imagine a seguinte situação: imagina que na `div.img` eu tenha uma `imagem` com `300px` de **altura** e resolva trocar por outra de `400px` de **altura** ou ainda de `200px`. Mantendo **altura fixa** na `div.slideShow`, terei problemas. Daí a necessidade do **ajuste automático**.

Como resolver esse problema?

Abaixo o código rodando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  quantasImagens = $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").length-1;
  contador = 0;
 
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior").click(function() {
   contador = contador==quantasImagens ?  -1 : contador;
   contador++;
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("opacity",0);
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(contador).css("opacity",1);
  });
  
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo").click(function() {
   contador = contador==0 ? quantasImagens+1 :  contador;
   contador--;
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("opacity",0);
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(contador).css("opacity",1);
  });
  
  $("div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide").click(function() {
   index = $(this).index();
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("opacity",0);
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(index).css("opacity",1);
  });
  
});
```

```css
 * {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
  
div.slideShow {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height:300px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide,
div.slideShow div.contador {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide{
 height:277px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img:first-child {
 opacity: 1;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior,  
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 100px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior {
 left: 100px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo {
 right: 100px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span.boxSpan, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span.boxSpan {
 background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
 opacity: .5;
 z-index: 1;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span.setaSpan, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span.setaSpan {
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bolder;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 2;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div span.setaSpan:hover + span.boxSpan {
 opacity: 1;
}
div.slideShow div.contador {
 /*top:240px;*/
 background-color:rgba(240,240,240,.5);
}
div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: .5;
}
div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideShow">
  <div class="boxSlide">
     <div class="imagens">
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" />
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" />
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" />
     </div>
     <div class="anterior">
        <span class="setaSpan"><</span>
        <span class="boxSpan"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="proximo">
        <span class="setaSpan">></span>
        <span class="boxSpan"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contador">
     <span class="contaSlide">1</span>
     <span class="contaSlide">2</span>
     <span class="contaSlide">3</span>
  </div>
</div>
oi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que faz isso é o `position: absolute` que tira o elemento do fluxo normal da página. Para resolver sem o `position: absolute` faça assim:

Primeiramente na sua classe `.boxSlide` deixe-a com o `height: auto` para ela se adaptar ao tamanho do conteúdo:

```
div.slideShow div.boxSlide {
    height:auto;
}
```

Depois remova o `position: absolute` das suas imagens para que elas voltem ao fluxo normal da página e esconda-as com o `display: none` ao invés de `opacity: 0` pois assim as imagens que não estiverem a mostra não vão ocupar espaço abaixo:

```
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: none;
}
```

E por fim deixamos a primeira imagem com `display: block`:

```
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

Agora no seu Javascript ao invés de mudar o `opacity` das imagens mudamos o `display` (faça isso nos outros trechos):

```
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("display", "none");
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(contador).css("display", "block");
```

Código completo funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  quantasImagens = $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").length-1;
  contador = 0;
 
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior").click(function() {
   contador = contador==quantasImagens ?  -1 : contador;
   contador++;
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("display", "none");
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(contador).css("display", "block");
  });
  
  $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo").click(function() {
   contador = contador==0 ? quantasImagens+1 :  contador;
   contador--;
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("display", "none");
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(contador).css("display", "block");
  });
  
  $("div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide").click(function() {
   index = $(this).index();
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").css("display", "none");
   $("div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img").eq(index).css("display", "block");
  });
  
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
 }
  
div.slideShow {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height:300px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide,
div.slideShow div.contador {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide{
 height:auto;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 display: none;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.imagens img:first-child {
 display: block;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior,  
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 100px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior {
 left: 100px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo {
 right: 100px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span.boxSpan, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span.boxSpan {
 background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
 opacity: .5;
 z-index: 1;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.anterior span.setaSpan, 
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div.proximo span.setaSpan {
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bolder;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 2;
}
div.slideShow div.boxSlide div span.setaSpan:hover + span.boxSpan {
 opacity: 1;
}
div.slideShow div.contador {
 /*top:240px;*/
 background-color:rgba(240,240,240,.5);
}
div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: .5;
}
div.slideShow div.contador span.contaSlide:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideShow">
  <div class="boxSlide">
     <div class="imagens">
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/1.png" />
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/2.png" />
       <img src="http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/_imgs/_slideShow/3.png" />
     </div>
     <div class="anterior">
        <span class="setaSpan">anterior</span>
        <span class="boxSpan"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="proximo">
        <span class="setaSpan">proximo</span>
        <span class="boxSpan"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contador">
     <span class="contaSlide">1</span>
     <span class="contaSlide">2</span>
     <span class="contaSlide">3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: então, mas isso não está resolvendo. Pois se eu coloco alguma coisa abaixo da div.total, esse conteúdo sobre pro incio da div.total. Bom, as imagens da div.img estão com position absolute e precisam se assim. Será isso?

Comment: Sim é exatamente isso, o postion: absolute faz com que o elemento 'saia' do fluxo normal, então ele não preenche o elemento pai

Comment: Existe algum recurso? Cheguei até colocar uma div com clear:both abaixo mas não resolveu

Comment: Faça o seguinte, edite sua resposta e no menu que aparece onde você edita o texto da pergunta clique em `Trecho Javascript/HTML/Css` e adicione o código html/css nos quadros que aparecerem, assim podemos 'ver' seu código rodando e fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: Mas quanto ao position: absolute não adianta o clear: both, isso funciona mais para floats, provavelmente terá que mudar esse position: absolute.

Comment: duvida completa aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247185/slideshow-n%C3%A3o-funciona-direito-ap%C3%B3s-migra%C3%A7%C3%A3o, procurei minimizar o problema nesse nosso tópico. Código rodando aqui: http://hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/slide.php

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67369/discussion-between-bruno-romualdo-and-carlos-rocha).

Comment: feito conforme sua orientação. Observe que, como as imagens reduziram de tamanho acompanhando o browser, a div do menu desceu muito por causa da altura fix da div principal

Comment: ok entre no chat, pra não ficar muito longo aqui.

Comment: mais um probleminha: desta vez com as setas. Note que embora ambas estão posicionadas à 100px das margens, embora eu tenha trocado aqui para 10%, a margem direita meio que não está respeitando isso quando diminuímos muito o browser

Comment: Isso foge da pergunta principal mas vou te responder no chat.

Comment: Se puder dar a pergunta como respondida agradeço :)

Comment: certeza. Pela tua solução, o meu erro estava em não tornar display:none nas outras div's que não estavam sendo mostradas. Então, todas ficavam display:block, empurrando as demais para baixo. este era o meu erro. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Sobre as div's das setas, a ideia aqui era criar um quadrado com background e opacity:0 e quando passar o mouse sobre ele, ele aparece com oacity:1

Answer (score 0):

Visto que as imagens teem `position: absolute`, eu sugeria que desse um `height` fixo às imagens, por exemplo `500px` e depois desse à `div` esse `height`.

Comment: Não posso. Exatamente por causa do layout responsivo.